# MongoID join on embedded documents

Tags: mongodb, mongoid

We have a Shipment document with an embedded ShipmentEvent document as in...

```
class Shipment
  include Mongoid::Document
  embeds_many :shipment_events
end

class ShipmentEvent
  include Mongoid::Document
  embedded_in :shipment
end
```

What we need to get is a join containing shipments and theirs latest shipment_event based on a :event_at field.

Example data (simplified with just one shipment):

```
[
  {
    "_id" => BSON::ObjectId('1'),
    "shipment_events" => [
      {
        "_id" => BSON::ObjectId('2'),
        "event_at" => 2022-04-09 15:00:00 UTC
      },
      {
        "_id" => BSON::ObjectId('3'),
        "event_at" => 2022-04-09 18:00:00 UTC
      }
    ]
  }
]
```

The result expected should contain the shipment and only the second (latest by :event_at) shipment_event. Something like...

```
[
  {
    "_id" => BSON::ObjectId('1'),
    "_event_id" => BSON::ObjectId('3'),
    "event_at" => 2022-04-09 18:00:00 UTC
  }
]
```

I know join queries are not possible with MongoId and we will need to use aggregation I guess. Any ideas will be appreciated.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do it this way:

```
unwind = { "$unwind" => "$shipment_events" }
sort = {
  "$sort" => {
    "_id" => 1, "shipment_events.event_at" => -1
  }
}
group = {
  "$group" => {
    "_id" => "$_id",
    "event_id" => {
      "$first" => "$$ROOT.shipment_events._id"
    },
    "event_at" => {
      "$first" => "$$ROOT.shipment_events.event_at"
    }
  }
}

Shipment.collection.aggregate([unwind, sort, group])
```

Please find playground example below.
https://mongoplayground.net/p/oLTG-18aIDm

Comment: Hi @PavelBely. Thanks very much for your clear answer. It looks like it is exactely what I am looking for. I will try it on my side. Regards.

Comment: @ManuelPalenciano happy to hear that, You're welcome